# Using the expression "at the time of"

Tags: grammar, expressions

I have the following two sentences:

> I met Jenifer on January fifth. At the time of our first meeting, she was unemployed.

I want to convey that Jenifer was unemployed for some time (probably months); it is not just during our meeting that she was unemployed. Will my sentence be understood correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you asking that here, rather than in a forum dealing with writing style, please?

Answer (score 0):

***[At the time of (something](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/at%20the%20time%20of%20(something))*** means:

> when (something) happened.
>
> - *It was raining at the time of the accident.*

The expression explicitly conveys the idea that two or more facts happen at the same time.

So if Jennifer was not unemployed at the time you met her, your sentence may give rise to misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence would be taken to mean that she *was* unemployed when you met her—but it would convey nothing beyond that. If you want to express something more, you need to be explicit about it:

> I met Jenifer on January fifth. At the time of our first meeting, she ***had been*** unemployed for (some time / several months).

Also note that you probably don't want to say *at the time of our* ***first*** *meeting*, because you haven't established anything yet about multiple meetings. Purely in the context of these two sentences, it would be better to say *at the time of* ***this*** *meeting*.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answer. Let's be more concrete: Jenifer was unemployed In December, January and February. So, ti was before, during and after meeting me.   If I say as you suggest that "..she had been unemployed.." will it be what I need?

Comment: @student There are many ways of expressing that—but note that you're now adding a "future" period relative to the past event. "When I met Jenifer in January, it was during her three months of unemployment last year." "When I met Jenifer in January, she had been unemployed for six weeks and would continue to be unemployed for another six weeks." And so on.